# Android: Layout proportional scale

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to simulate microcontrolers screen (800x480) on android devices. Screen content is buttons, labels, graphic primitives(line, rect, ...), images.
What to do to fit layout (scale up/down) on all screens?

Here is layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="800px"
android:minHeight="480px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="800px"
    android:minHeight="480px"
    android:layout_width="800px"
    android:layout_height="480px"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer">
  <NSU.Droid.MyWindow
      android:minWidth="714px"
      android:layout_width="714px"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/mainWindow"
      android:background="@drawable/window_shape"
      android:layout_margin="1dp" />
  <LinearLayout
      android:minWidth="86px"
      android:layout_width="86px"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/sidewindow_shape"
      android:layout_margin="1px"
      android:scrollbars="none">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <NSU.Droid.SideWindow
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:minWidth="86px"
          android:layout_width="86px"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/sideWindow"
          android:scrollbars="none" />
    </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

NSU.Droid.MyWindow is RelativeLayout.
If px is used, simulated layout is too small, about 1/3 on my device screen. Changing px to dp does not help - view is too big, I can see about 2/3 of layout content.
How to scale layout and content proportionally?

Answer (score 0):

Use `match_parent` for `android:layour_width` or `android:layout_height` attributes to fit screen with layout.
To make items sizes proportional, you can use `android:layout_weight` attribute in `LinearLayout`.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you have horizontal orientation of your `LinearLayout`, you should set `android:layout_width` attribute to `0dp` to elements of this `LinearLayout` to which you want apply `android:layout_weight` attribute. If orientation of your `LinearLayout` is vertical then `android:layout_height` attribute should be set to `0dp`.

The XML above should look like this:

[image: Weights]

Comment: Content is created runtime. I'm reading microcontrollers UI file and creating views runtime inside RelativeLayout, specifying size in pixels. So I have fixed size layout - 800x480px (containing ImageViews, Buttons, TextViews). And now I need scale this layout with content to fill available space, bigger or smaller, proportionally. How to do this?